# Regex to retrieve last digits from a string and sort them

Tags: java, regex, sorting

I have a list of string which I want to sort them using the last digits present in the string, I have tried this using below code, but for some reasons, it's picking digit present before the last digit as well, for instance in "abc\xyz 2 5" string it's picking 25 instead of just 5 because of which it is sorting it incorrectly. May I know what's incorrect in my regex?

Note: My last two digits will always be timestamp like 1571807700009 1571807700009.

Here's what I have tried so far.

```
public static void second() {   
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("abc\\xyz 2 5", "abc\\\\xyz 1 8", "abc\\\\xyz 1 9", "abc\\\\xyz 1 7", "abc\\\\xyz 1 3");       
Collections.sort(strings, new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return (int) (extractInt(o1) - extractInt(o2));
        }

        Long extractInt(String s) {
            String num = s.replaceAll("\\D", "");
            return Long.parseLong(num);
        }
    });
    System.out.println(strings);
```

}

Output

```
[abc\\xyz 1 3, abc\\xyz 1 7, abc\\xyz 1 8, abc\\xyz 1 9, abc\xyz 2 5]
```

Expected Output

```
[abc\\xyz 1 3, abc\\xyz 2 5, abc\\xyz 1 7, abc\\xyz 1 8, abc\xyz 1 9]
```

Comment: \d+$ to get the last number next to the end line character

Comment: Refering to your edit: Your strings look like "abc\\xyz 123 567" and "abc\\xyz 456 987" and you want to compare 567 to 987?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a stream, sort only on the last integer by replacing the previous portion of the string with an empty string.  You can also take advantage of the API `Comparator` interface by passing that value to the comparing method.

```java
   List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("abc\\xyz 2 5", "abc\\\\xyz 1 8",
      "abc\\\\xyz 1 9", "abc\\\\xyz 1 7", "abc\\\\xyz 1 3");

   strings = strings.stream()
       .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> Long.valueOf(s.replaceAll(".*\\s+", ""))))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());

   System.out.println(strings);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , but It's not working for long digits like timestamp 1571807700009

Comment: @saurabhkumar  Then just change to the Long.valueOf() method.  I changed it to accomodate your requirement.

Comment: still, I am getting exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:abc//def 1571807280003

Comment: @saurabhkumar I apologize for this.  I assumed fixed format.  My bad.  Try it now.

Comment: @saurabhkumar  Well, I'm not sure what the problem is.  It works for me with the long values substituted in the example strings you provided.  I am sorry I was unable to help you.

Comment: abc\\xyz 2 1571807700009 can you try with this string

Comment: @saurabhkumar That's because it expects 2 numbers, as in your example.  That is easily fixed.  Try it as soon as I edit.

Comment: Working perfectly,Thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 3):

Change your `extractInt` method to this to remove everything except last number from input:

```
Long extractInt(String s) {
    String num = s.replaceFirst("^.+\\b(\\d+)$", "$1");
    return Long.parseLong(num);
}
```

This regex is matching a greedy match at start `.+` to make sure to match longest string before matching `\d+` in the end after matching word boundary using `\b`.

This will give following output:

```
[abc\\xyz 1 3, abc\xyz 2 5, abc\\xyz 1 7, abc\\xyz 1 8, abc\\xyz 1 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to sort your strings by comparing only the last digit, you even don't need to parse that digit to int or long. Assuming your strings have always a digit at the end:

```
Function<String,String> lastDigit = s -> s.substring(s.length()-1);
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("abc\\xyz 2 5", "abc\\\\xyz 1 8", "abc\\\\xyz 1 9", "abc\\\\xyz 1 7", "abc\\\\xyz 1 3"); 

System.out.println("Before sorting: " + strings);

strings.sort(Comparator.comparing(lastDigit));

System.out.println("After sorting: " + strings);
```

**EDIT**

You don't seem to compare only the last digit as assumed at the beginning, but the last number after the last space character. If this is the case use the similar approach below

```
Function<String,Long> lastNum = s -> Long.valueOf(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(" ")+1));
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("abc\\xyz 2 5", "abc\\\\xyz 1 8", "abc\\\\xyz 1 9", "abc\\\\xyz 1 7", "abc\\\\xyz 1 3"); 

System.out.println("Before sorting: " + strings);

strings.sort(Comparator.comparing(lastNum));

System.out.println("After sorting: " + strings);
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare the last number in each string you can just substring from the last space and then parse to a Long.

I.e.

```
strings = strings.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(
        s -> parseLong(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1))
    )).collect(Collectors.toList());
```